# Does China have a separation of power between legislative and executive branch? What is the equivalent of a Minister in China?

Tags: china, separation-of-powers

Note: Please don't devote a good percentage of your answer on criticizing China and its way of governance. Try to be explanatory and not judgemental.

So far, I have only able to grasp that China is controlled completely by The Communist Party. The Party have millions of members, out of these members the National People's Congress (may be a little equivalent to USA's Congress) and then this Congress appoints a Standing Committee for day-to-day work.

What I don't get is how everyday execution and planning goes on? The National People's Congress meet only once a year and Standing Committee have just 7 member, how does do they propose law, discuss it, pass it and implement it? Does the President of China exercise any legislative power?

In order not to let the question be very broad, I would like you to simply compare the legislative and executive model of UK (or US if you like) with China.

Comment: The key is to understand that the formal procedures and structures of the Chinese state do not necessarily correspond (at all) to how things actually work internally. Also, the Standing Committee of the NPC doesn’t have 7 members, it has 175. You’re thinking of the Standing Committee of the CPC.

Comment: @HHuang Well, I mean even the internal working must be requiring a lot of people, given that China is such a powerful and stable country at global level (unlike Afghanistan and Pakistan). Can you differentiate between the workings of those two Standing Committees?

Comment: This is an interesting question because it asks a study of "what on earth? is the Chinese administrations mechanism of regulation for the legal/executive/legislative branches?" 1/ it's opaque, little and very limited freedom of information, so we don't know 2/ It's a technocratic dictatorship: 1/ the leader has cronies 2/ the cronies enforce programs.

Comment: In addition to the NPC and the Standing Commitee, there is also the [State Council](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_Council_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China).

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Government of China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_of_China) covers a lot of this, and links to other relevant articles like [Ministries of the People's Republic of China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministries_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China).

Answer (score 5):

I did some digging and found that Xi published an article in Qiushi journal, the Chinese Communist Party’s main theoretical periodical, which states that that:

*China must never copy the models or practices of other countries. We must never follow the path of Western ‘constitutionalism,’ ‘separation of powers,’ or ‘judicial independence,’ Xi said.*

He called for strengthening the Communist Party’s leadership over law in China.

In 2017, the CCP had already added *“Party, government, military, civilian, and academic, east, west, south, north, and center, the party leads everything”* — the phrase coined by Mao Zedong — into the CCP’s constitution. By doing so, the CCP has officially placed itself in charge of everything.

Comment: ...and Xi leads the Party. Period.